# Meteor Modal not displaying in an {{#each}} iterator

Tags: meteor, modal-dialog

I have been tinkering to get a modal up running

I have a button that opens a modal which is within an {{#each }}, i want the button to be available for each iteration.

On clicking the button looks like there is something which is stopping the modal from opening and i am not sure what.

I have the following button in my template

```
<template name="myTemplateName">
    <form>
        {{#each listOfItems}}
            some stuff here....
            <button class="btn" data-modal="emailMe">Email Me</button>
        {{/each}}
    </form>
</template>
```

I have the following event

```
Template.myTemplateName.events({
  'click button': function(event, template){
   var modalName = "modal_signIn";
   Modal.show(modalName);
  }
})
```

when i move the button outside the {{#each}} statement the modal comes up. How can i achieve this functionality

Comment: Update : when i use ahref instead of a button with approproate changes to event it works inside the {{#each}}, button still dosent

Answer (score 0):

In the `{{#each}}` block you'll have multiple button elements. Nest another template within the `{{#each}}` block and then attach the button event to that inner template.